# Starting incognito mode in chrome on detecting a specific string in search bar

Tags: python, google-chrome, webbrowser-control

is it possible to code to have my google chrome to automatically open the incognito mode on detecting a specific string of URL in search bar? for example if i type 'fb.com' on search bar the chrome automatically opens the incognito tab.is it possible through python?

Comment: Use the os module to execute the command.

import os
os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -ArgumentList @( '-incognito', 'www.fb.com'" )

Comment: so am i supposed to place this code in some chrome directory and then everytime i if i search for fb.com in chrome search bar, it will open in incognito mode?
if yes, then where??

Comment: This code will make you easily open chrome in the incognito mode as a program in your system.